# .htaccess RewriteRule Old URL to New URL for images

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I'm new to working in .htaccess and I'm trying to redirect an old development URL to the new live site URL for image sources.

I had a website on a development server with the following URL:
http://www.dev.testname.com

I transferred it to a new server with a new URL:
http://www.sitename.com

I have images that are still referencing the http://www.dev.testname.com server, through .htaccess how can I point that URL to the new URL?

I have tried:

```
 RewriteRule http://www.dev.testname.com http://www.sitename.com
 Redirect 301 http://www.dev.testname.com http://www.sitename.com
```

Comment: Just point old address to new IP

Comment: Did you try these rules on the old server or on the new server?